# What to put in OpenDirect field for MobilePush to direct to a page within the app

Tags: marketing-cloud, mobilepush

We need to send messages to MobilePush subscribers in the Marketing Cloud that link directly to a page within the app. I've activated OpenDirect for the account, but I don't know what information to put in the message's OpenDirect field to direct the user to the page. I've scoured the help files and can't find anything. Any guidance would be sincerely appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

this is a two part answer.

First you'll need to write your app to register, understand and route custom urls. This is an OS feature, that allows you to register a url scheme, something like myApp:// along with urls for a given "page". think something like myApp://billing

Once you've gotten that taken care of, you can send an open Direct message with your custom URL. Make sense?

Writing the code for your app to register and handle custom urls is a bit outside the scope of this stack exchange, but these docs should help get you started with the ios side: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/Inter-AppCommunication/Inter-AppCommunication.html

Comment: Do you know if Open Direct is available for Android ?

Comment: @zeljazoui, I believe it is.